# Issue in processing the fetched data-set from another method (http)

Tags: angular, http, subscribe

I'm having this issue with using Angular http requests. Please have a look at the following code snippets.

**http-service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../../../environments/environment';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

const BASE_URL = environment.API.MAIN.PATH;
const WAR = environment.API.MAIN.WAR;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService {
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getITById(id) {
    return this.http.get(`${BASE_URL}/${WAR}/events/find?id=${id}`);
  }
}
```

**app-component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpService} from '../../services/http-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  processPart(idToPass) {
    // get the loaded value from requesPart(idToPass); function and process that data set in this function.
    let data = requestPart(idToPass);
  }

  requestPart(id) {
    // (1)
    return this.httpService.getITById(id)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          console.log(data)
        }, error => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
  }

}
```

This is the problem. I know the implementation I've made in (1) is wrong (this will return the subscriber object). I want to know how to get the dataset fetched from the `requestPart(id);` method to process in the `processPart(idToPass);` method.

Project structure cannot be changed and the http-service cannot be imported into the component (as some of the existing solutions suggested)

Would appreciate if someone can point out what am I missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return data;`?

Comment: nope! It returns `undefined`. I tried that approach, but it doesn't return the dataset. Because `requestPart(idToPass);` is looking to get the returned data from `requestPart(id)`. not the subscribe method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
requestPart(id) {
    // (1)
    this.httpService.getITById(id)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
          if(data)
          {
            return data;
          }
        }, error => {
          console.error(error);
        }
   );
}
```

Comment: It returns `undefined`. I tried that approach, but it doesn't return the dataset. Because `requestPart(idToPass);` is looking to get the returned data from `requestPart(id)`. not the subscribe method.

Comment: CAn you provide demo in the stackblitz?

Comment: The call to the `requestPart` method is async so your flow of control reach to next line before that method getting called!

Comment: Yes, I know that the issue is that. I'm looking for an optimum solution rather than having a controller to wait until the method is called or setting a time out.